Rust ode_solvers get all the states throughout an integration (for plotting)
I am trying to learn to use the ode_solvers crate in rust, the documentation and (more informative) github docs can be found at:
https://docs.rs/ode_solvers/latest/ode_solvers/
https://srenevey.github.io/ode-solvers/index.html
I have been able to run simulations. However, I cannot work out how to get the values given by the steps in order to plot the path. E.g. one of the examples given in their documentation is a kepler orbit https://srenevey.github.io/ode-solvers/examples/kepler_orbit.html where they show a plot of the orbit but as far as I can see they do not show how it was plotted and I cannot work out how extract the values that the integration gives.
Please let me know how to extract the final and intermediate values so I can plot the path. Thanks,
The code for the kepler orbit example is:
use ode_solvers::{self, dop853::*};

type State = ode_solvers::Vector6<f64>;
type Time = f64;

struct KeplerOrbit {
    mu: f64,
}

impl ode_solvers::System<Time, State> for KeplerOrbit {
    // Equations of motion of the system
    fn system(&self, _t: Time, y: &State, dy: &mut State) {
        let r = (y[0] * y[0] + y[1] * y[1] + y[2] * y[2]).sqrt();

        dy[0] = y[3];
        dy[1] = y[4];
        dy[2] = y[5];
        dy[3] = - self.mu * y[0] / r.powi(3);
        dy[4] = - self.mu * y[1] / r.powi(3);
        dy[5] = - self.mu * y[2] / r.powi(3);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let system = KeplerOrbit {mu: 398600.435436};

    let a: f64 = 20000.0;
    let period = 2.0 * std::f64::consts::PI * (a.powi(3) / system.mu).sqrt();
    let y0 = State::new(-5007.248417988539, -1444.918140151374, 3628.534606178356, 0.717716656891, -10.224093784269, 0.748229399696);

    let mut stepper = Dop853::new(system, 0.0, 5.0 * period, 60.0, y0, 1.0e-10, 1.0e-10);
    let res = stepper.integrate();

    // Handle result
    match res {
        Ok(stats) => {
            println!("stats: {:?}", stats)
            
        },
        Err(_) => println!("An error occured."),
    }
}


Your system function has the coordinates → just save them there.

I may be misunderstanding you but I don't believe that will work, the dormad prince algorithm used in the example sometimes accepts and sometimes rejects steps (depending on the errors involved), for example if you run the code here the stats printed at the end are stats: Stats { num_eval: 4722, accepted_steps: 253, rejected_steps: 84 } meaning if I modified the system function to store the co-ordinates each time it was called it would result in a lot of co-ordinates from rejected steps being stored and therefore the path being plotted incorrectly.

If you are instead talking about the system variable defined on the first line of the main function then please let me know how I can extract the co-ordinates (as far as I can see it only stores the mu variable of type f64

Ah, right you will also get the rejected steps. However stepper has the x_out method, which I believe will give you what you want.

In this case it would be y_out but yes that works great thanks. If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it so I can close the question.

Your system variable has x_out and y_out methods which you can use after integration to get the values for each integration step.
